# Is the following approach to show login screen on iPhone secure?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, authentication

I have an app where the user has to login to see his data which is stored in the server.
I have a `UIWebView` instance in my `rootViewController` where I show the retrieved data. I have the following code in the `viewWillAppear` call of the `rootViewController` to authenticate the user...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if(![self isUserLoggedin]) {

         if( loginViewController == nil ) {
            loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
            loginViewController.delegate = self;
        }

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If the user enters the correct password I pop the loginViewController and fetch the data and display in the webView.

I would like to know if this is a safe way, or does it have any security issues? Is there any standard way to show the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are ***accepting***, ***using*** and ***saving*** Login Credentials securely it should not matter if you are pushing the `LoginViewController`.

How ever, presenting the `LoginViewController` on `self.navigationController` and dismissing it on success would have been a better approach. This again has nothing to do with security. But I would prefer this because

1. An unnecessary addition to navigation stack will be avoided.
2. Presenting it as a modal gives the user a better experience ;)